# trying to do rot13-like solution that can process special chars

Tags: bash, sed, tr

I want to implement a take on the rot13 function that uses a randomly generated alpha-num keys, but I also want to include special chars and can't seem to get that to work. This function using `tr` command including special chars does not work:

```
echo "$@" | tr "aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|" "A*KWx#o(5I-j\e|Hv)X7R0SJ=8+tBE^ucOVgMd2l$QkafU4nqz36LPhGb1rmswi%FC@!D_p9N&YyZT"
```

So I wrote a much more convoluted function that splits a word's letters into an array and then passes each array ele thru a `for` loop that consists of 92 if/elif statements that when a char is matched then runs a `sed` replace sub:

```
conv=""
x="$1" ; echo "\$1: ${1}"
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#x} ]; do y[$i]=${x:$i:1};  i=$((i+1));done
for f in "${y[@]}" ; do
    newF=$(echo "$f"|if [[ "$f" == "a" ]] ; then sed -r 's/a/7/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "A" ]] ; then sed -r 's/A/\?/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "b" ]] ; then sed -r 's/b/v/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "B" ]] ; then sed -r 's/B/\./g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "c" ]] ; then sed -r 's/c/q/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "C" ]] ; then sed -r 's/C/2/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "d" ]] ; then sed -r 's/d/m/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "D" ]] ; then sed -r 's/D/\Z/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "e" ]] ; then sed -r 's/e/S/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "E" ]] ; then sed -r 's/E/y/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "f" ]] ; then sed -r 's/f/d/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "F" ]] ; then sed -r 's/F/\)/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "g" ]] ; then sed -r 's/g/z/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "G" ]] ; then sed -r 's/G/K/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "h" ]] ; then sed -r 's/h/T/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "H" ]] ; then sed -r 's/H/\{/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "i" ]] ; then sed -r 's/i/8/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "I" ]] ; then sed -r 's/I/H/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "j" ]] ; then sed -r 's/j/p/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "J" ]] ; then sed -r 's/J/A/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "k" ]] ; then sed -r 's/k/@/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "K" ]] ; then sed -r 's/K/R/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "l" ]] ; then sed -r 's/l/W/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "L" ]] ; then sed -r 's/L/9/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "m" ]] ; then sed -r 's/m/s/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "M" ]] ; then sed -r 's/M/\(/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "n" ]] ; then sed -r 's/n/V/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "N" ]] ; then sed -r 's/N/t/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "o" ]] ; then sed -r 's/o/\\/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "O" ]] ; then sed -r 's/O/\!/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "p" ]] ; then sed -r 's/p/=/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "P" ]] ; then sed -r 's/P/n/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "q" ]] ; then sed -r 's/q/#/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "Q" ]] ; then sed -r 's/Q/e/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "r" ]] ; then sed -r 's/r/g/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "R" ]] ; then sed -r 's/R/f/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "s" ]] ; then sed -r 's/s/-/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "S" ]] ; then sed -r 's/S/0/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "t" ]] ; then sed -r 's/t/,/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "T" ]] ; then sed -r 's/T/:/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "u" ]] ; then sed -r 's/u/_/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "U" ]] ; then sed -r 's/U/Q/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "v" ]] ; then sed -r 's/v/i/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "V" ]] ; then sed -r 's/V/k/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "w" ]] ; then sed -r 's/w/w/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "W" ]] ; then sed -r 's/W/l/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "x" ]] ; then sed -r 's/x/3/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "X" ]] ; then sed -r 's/X/\]/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "y" ]] ; then sed -r 's/y/5/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "Y" ]] ; then sed -r 's/Y/O/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "z" ]] ; then sed -r 's/z/F/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "Z" ]] ; then sed -r 's/Z/"/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "0" ]] ; then sed -r 's/0/;/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "1" ]] ; then sed -r 's/1/E/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "2" ]] ; then sed -r 's/2/>/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "3" ]] ; then sed -r 's/3/u/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "4" ]] ; then sed -r 's/4/\$/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "5" ]] ; then sed -r 's/5/</g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "6" ]] ; then sed -r 's/6/\+/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "7" ]] ; then sed -r 's/7/x/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "8" ]] ; then sed -r 's/8/L/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "9" ]] ; then sed -r 's/9/C/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "!" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\!/a/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "@" ]] ; then sed -r 's/@/\//g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "#" ]] ; then sed -r 's/#/M/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "$" ]] ; then sed -r "s/\$/'/g" ; elif [[ "$f" == "%" ]] ; then sed -r 's/%/1/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "^" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\^/c/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "&" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\&/h/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "*" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\*/U/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "(" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\(/\|/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == ")" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\)/\[/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "-" ]] ; then sed -r 's/-/I/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "_" ]] ; then sed -r 's/_/\*/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "=" ]] ; then sed -r 's/=/G/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "+" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\+/P/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "|" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\|/o/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == '\' ]] ; then sed -r 's/\\/Y/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "[" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\[/j/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "{" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\{/B/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "]" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\]/\%/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "}" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\}/J/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == ";" ]] ; then sed -r 's/;/X/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == ":" ]] ; then sed -r 's/:/\^/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "'" ]] ; then sed -r "s/'/D/g"; elif [[ "$f" == '"' ]] ; then sed -r 's/"/\}/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "," ]] ; then sed -r 's/,/4/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "<" ]] ; then sed -r 's/</r/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "." ]] ; then sed -r 's/\./N/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == ">" ]] ; then sed -r 's/>/\&/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "/" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\//6/g' ; elif [[ "$f" == "?" ]] ; then sed -r 's/\?/b/g' ; fi)
    echo "converting: $f to $newF"
    conv="${conv}${newF}" ; echo "\$conv: ${conv}"
done
```

It works now, sort of, but not quite. I need to enter input words to be converted enclosed in single quotes, due to the special chars handling it seems (lots of trial and error to figure that one out!), which is all fine except how do I enter a word to be converted if it contains a single quote char?

Ultimately I would prefer to use a simpler solution such as with the `tr` command if anyone has advice how how to manage special chars using `tr` that would be great. If not then how can I enter a word containing special chars including a single quote if the input seems to need to be encased in single quotes?

Unicodes maybe? But that sounds like an even uglier solution than what I already have.

**Additional Info:** Hey Gene thanks for the quick replies. It's almost there, a lot further than I managed. I did totally forget about dashes, but I usually only think of those when enclosing them in square brackets, remembering they need to be the last chars specified to avoid defining an unwanted range.

All of the translated letters that come after the first escaped char in the second (translated) set of chars, the dash `-`, adds an offset; and every subsequent escaped after that char adds one more offset to the result. So for:

```
$ echo 'h3!10 w()rLd'|tr 'aAbBcCdDeEFGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()\-_=+\\|' 'A*KWx#o(5I\-j\\e|Hv)X7R0SJ=8+tBE^ucOVgMd2l$QkafU4nqz36LPhGb1rmswi%FC@!D_p9&YyT'
```

the result is:

```
\Ps63 kD_c0o
```

but should be:

<strike>|5iPL fp9VJo</strike>
I mistakenly x-referenced "e" instead of "3", so make that:

```
|GiPL fp9VJo
```

All out by two places. I could probably whip up a hack to calculate the escaped chars and adjust accordingly, but it seems strange that incorporating special chars should be so dawg gone difficult. I even tried to put them into array elements, which would be not a bad way to go either, but bash balks back about that too.

I have been using a spreadsheet to make the char x-references as easy as possible. But here they are side-by-side:

```
a <=> A   n <=> +   0 <=> L  
A <=> *   N <=> t   1 <=> P  
b <=> K   o <=> B   2 <=> h  
B <=> W   O <=> E   3 <=> G  
c <=> x   p <=> ^   4 <=> b  
C <=> #   P <=> u   5 <=> 1  
d <=> o   q <=> c   6 <=> r  
D <=> (   Q <=> O   7 <=> m  
e <=> 5   r <=> V   8 <=> s  
E <=> I   R <=> g   9 <=> w  
f <=> -   s <=> M   ! <=> i  
F <=> j   S <=> d   @ <=> %  
g <=> \   t <=> 2   # <=> F  
G <=> e   T <=> l   $ <=> C  
h <=> |   u <=> $   % <=> @  
H <=> H   U <=> Q   ^ <=> !  
i <=> v   v <=> k   & <=> D  
I <=> )   V <=> a   * <=> _  
j <=> X   w <=> f   ( <=> p  
J <=> 7   W <=> U   ) <=> 9  
k <=> R   x <=> 4   - <=> N  
K <=> 0   X <=> n   _ <=> &  
l <=> S   y <=> q   = <=> Y  
L <=> J   Y <=> z   + <=> y  
m <=> =   z <=> 3   | <=> Z  
M <=> 8   Z <=> 6   \ <=> T
```

**Yet more info:** so I went another, probably more inefficient way, but got everything to work fine now; except there is still no way to enter a string that contains both single and dbl quotes, so unless there is a way around that which I have not yet found then I will just have to keep that limit in mind when using the following script:

```
# array containing regular alphaNumSpecChar
abc=(a b c d e f g h i j k l m n o p q r s t u v w x y z A B C D E F G H I J K L M N O P Q R S T U V W X Y Z 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9 '!' '@' '#' '$' '%' '^' '&' '*' '(' ')' '-' '_' '=' '+' '|' '\' '[' '{' ']' '}' ';' ':' "'" '"' ',' '.' '/' '?' '<' '>') #; echo "${#abc[@]}"

# randomly generated array key to cross-reference array elements in "$abc[@]}", so that if user input charater being processed is "b", "${abc[1]}" then the value for "${ranNum[2]}", 41 is used to convert "b" to "${abc[41]}", which is "P" 
ranNum=(40 41 47 52 1 68 20 54 17 2 59 13 11 57 90 33 82 4 31 70 29 26 83 63 56 38 28 61 25 32 49 43 23 45 64 55 9 69 44 60 91 5 84 88 22 14 62 87 7 86 39 78 48 46 58 73 3 6 16 8 37 72 74 67 80 35 77 66 89 53 12 79 42 27 21 18 65 0 75 85 34 10 15 19 76 50 51 71 81 36 24 30)

# var for conversion result
convRes=""

# while loop to map user's input string's individual chars to array 'y' 
x="$1" #; echo "\$1: ${1}"
i=0
while [ $i -lt ${#x} ]; do
    y[$i]=${x:$i:1}
    i=$((i+1))
done


for f in "${y[@]}" ; do     # for loop to process each array element from user's input string
    cntr1=0
    while [[ "$cntr" -le "${#abc[@]}" ]] ; do   # while loop to cycle thru all elements in array "${abc[@]}" to figure out what char it is
        if [[ "$f" == "${abc[$cntr1]}" ]] ; then        #'if' user input char is matched then using value of "$cntr1" var cross reference applicable random char conversion number
            convNum="${ranNum[$cntr1]}" #; echo "\$convNum: ${convNum}"
            #echo "converting: $f to $convNum"
            # append current converted char to $convRes var
            convRes="${convRes}${abc[$convNum]}" #; echo "\$convRes: ${convRes}"
            break
        fi
        ((cntr1++))
    done
done

echo -e "\n\$convRes: ${convRes}\n"
```

So if user enters:

```
$ rotateRandom.sh 'h3!1()W0rLd'
```

script returns:

```
$convRes: 2_b@m{hWe*0
```

The result I was initially hoping for using `tr` and if it can be had using that much easier solution, letter for letter than includes special chars I would use it, but for all my attempts to get `tr` to map correctly I was unsuccessful. Maybe I was just looking at and editing the same command too long and too many times to see the easy solution.

Comment: Try single quotes around the `tr` strings.  Or else you must escape the special characters with backslash.  You did it in other strings!  The `tr` command will work fine if you provide correct arguments.

Comment: @Gene actually I have played with this until my head feels like it will explode. I have tried both single and double quotes; i just tried escaping the special chars as you suggested, again using both single and dbl quotes, still no love. The lowercase letters always seem to translate fine (as expected) but the uppercase letter tend either to translate to some unexpected char or the same char for each uppercase letter is typed in. Very strange and driving me nuts. Do you mind copying the `tr` I included and running at cli to see if it works for you?

Comment: I fixed the problems.  See article below.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is first that you need single quotes around the `tr` arguments to prevent `bash` from expanding `$` in the strings.  Also, you've forgotten that `tr` treats a few characters specially:

- The dash `-` creates character sets.
- Backslash escapes whatever follows it.

This fixes up these problems by backslash escaping the dashes and the backslashes.

```
tr 'aAbBcCdDeEFGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()\-_=+\\|' \
   'A*KWx#o(5I\-j\\e|Hv)X7R0SJ=8+tBE^ucOVgMd2l$QkafU4nqz36LPhGb1rmswi%FC@!D_p9&YyT'
```

It's working fine in my `mingw` `bash`.

You didn't use square brackets `[`, but if you do in the future, beware that these can cause problems, too, if not escaped.

**Addition**

Addressing the OP's assertion that this isn't correct, I can't see how.  Using the escaped strings above but removing the backslashes to show the equivalences:

```
Plain:  aAbBcCdDeEFGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+\|
Cypher: A*KWx#o(5I-j\e|Hv)X7R0SJ=8+tBE^ucOVgMd2l$QkafU4nqz36LPhGb1rmswi%FC@!D_p9&YyT
```

Translating by hand:

```
h3!10 w()rLd
\Ps63 kD_c0o
```

Yet the OP's "should be" string is something different. Maybe I don't understand what we're trying to accomplish.

**Implementing OP's new table**

Your new table is not what you have in the `tr` command line.  Here is the corresponding translation (which I got from a little Ruby script with your table as input):

```
Plain:  aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()-_=+|\
Cypher: A*KWx#o(5I-j\e|Hv)X7R0SJ=8+tBE^ucOVgMd2l$QkafU4nqz36LPhGb1rmswi%FC@!D_p9N&YyZT
```

Note this is just your table displayed horizontally.  Nothing fancy.

The resulting `tr` command with backslash escapes added is just

```
echo 'h3!10 w()rLd' | \
tr 'aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()\-_=+|\\' \
   'A*KWx#o(5I\-j\\e|Hv)X7R0SJ=8+tBE^ucOVgMd2l$QkafU4nqz36LPhGb1rmswi%FC@!D_p9N&YyZT'
```

On my box this prints:

```
|GiPL fp9VJo
```

Or switch the parameters to go the other direction (because your cypher is not symmetric).

```
echo '|GiPL fp9VJo' | \
tr 'A*KWx#o(5I\-j\\e|Hv)X7R0SJ=8+tBE^ucOVgMd2l$QkafU4nqz36LPhGb1rmswi%FC@!D_p9N&YyZT' \
   'aAbBcCdDeEfFgGhHiIjJkKlLmMnNoOpPqQrRsStTuUvVwWxXyYzZ0123456789!@#$%^&*()\-_=+|\\'
```

This produces

```
h3!10 w()rLd
```

on my box, just as you'd expect.

Comment: added some addition info OP.

Comment: @nanker I can't see how you got the `h3!10 w()rLd` translation that you said was correct.  The `tr` command is working fine.  See my addition above.

Comment: I added a table with the two sets of chars side-by-side as they should translate, illustrating what appears to me to be what the chars should translate to. Perhaps I am wrong, I have been looking at this wayyyyyy too long I think, but the table looks right, which if so, then the escaped chars seem to be injecting an offset. I now think trying to manipulate special char is a much bigger headache than I ever imagined, so I am not surprised. None of the avenues I have tried has been straightforward.

Comment: @nanker  I think you need to take a breath or get some sleep.  The `tr` command will work fine if you give it a correct translation table.  See my new addition.

Comment: yes you are correct, the `tr` command does work fine now, and that is after some sleep. I was messing with so many variations of single and dbl quotes and escape chars that I was comparing the wrong chars. Sheesh! my bad. Sorry and thanks for your perseverance because the `tr` command is the way to go being so much more concise.

Answer (score 1):

There are two problems with your original solution with 'tr':

1. You're using double quotes, but there is a $ inside, which is special to the shell.
2. Your translation is not symmetric: a is translated to A, but A is translated to *.

I would probably do this with sed -e 'y///' (or maybe python), but one advantage of tr is that you can use characters sets:

```
tr '[:upper:][:lower:]' '[:lower:][:upper:]'
```

But either way you have to list out the special character pairs yourself.

Comment: +1 for two good points. But even sun4 sed supported character sets. and more importantly wouldn't  `tr 'ABC...abc...' 'abc...ABC...'` which the equivalent of your `tr` solution, just change the case? My `tr` says `...: invalid destination string. Sorry, but +1-1=0 ;-/ . Good luck.

Comment: @o11c addressed 1. in my comment above. The translation is not meant to be symmetric if I understand you right. I want to translate each letter from user's input to a random- crytic-seeming result. The `tr` command then would be the easiest solution for changing the random translation pattern as desired.